# Web view переход по ссылке

Tags: swift, webview

Нужна помощь, у меня есть приложение с `WebView`, оно открывает определенный сайт `www.example.com`. На этом сайте есть ссылки как на разделы этого сайта, так и на другие сайты `www.examlpe2.ru`, мне нужно чтобы переход на эти ссылки был в Safari. Как это реализовать?

Я новичок в разработке под iOS , а сроки не позволяют по хорошему изучить язык.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кратко:

1 протокол для класса `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

2 Подписываемся:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    browser.delegate = self
}
```

3 Указываем, что при переходе по ссылке открывать во внешнем приложении:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == .linkClicked {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

P.S. Это базово. Далее можно изменять условия что куда, добавить `canOpenURL(_:)`, настроить url схемы, заменить на  `UIApplication.shared.open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)` (для iOS 10+) и прочее